# Laravel 5.0のPaginationで「Next」「Prev」の文字を表示したい

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel 5.0 でPaginationを行う際、ページ番号などを表示せずに「Next」「Prev」の文字でページリンクをつけようとしています。
通常そのような場合 `simplePaginate()` を使うと思いますが、`render()` するとギュメ記号（`&laquo; &raquo;`）のみが表示され、文字はありません。

言語ファイル`resources/lang/en/pagination.php`を見ると`'previous' => '&laquo; Previous'`のような記述があったのですが書き換えても変化がありません。

`vendor`フォルダの`SimpleBootstrapThreePresenter.php`にある `getPreviousButton()` の引数を指定することでこの文字が代わる仕組みのようですが、自分でこれに代わるカスタムクラスを作る必要があるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

SimpleBootstrapThreePresenter の render() 内にある、 `$this->getPreviousButton()` と `$this->getNextButton()` の引数に値を入れられるような仕組みは用意されていないようなので、自分でこれに代わるカスタムクラスを作る必要があると思われます。

SimpleBootstrapThreePresenter を継承して、render をオーバーライドし、`$this->getPreviousButton()` と `$this->getNextButton()` に値を渡せるようにすることで実現できそうです。

```
public function render()
{
    if ($this->hasPages())
    {
        return sprintf(
            '<ul class="pager">%s %s</ul>',
            $this->getPreviousButton(trans('pagination.previous')),
            $this->getNextButton(trans('pagination.next'))
        );
    }
    return '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

config/app.phpで

```
'locale' => 'ja'
```

と設定しているようでしたら、
resources/lang 内に jaディレクトリを作成し、その中に
pagination.php

```
<?php

return [

    'previous' => '&laquo; 前へ',
    'next'     => '次へ &raquo;',

];
```

といった感じで設置すれば動作すると思います。

Comment: localeはenなのでenディレクトリ内のpagination.phpを使っています。そちらの初期値は「'previous' => '&laquo; Previous'」となっていますがrender()ではそのように表示されないようです。localeをjaに変えてjaフォルダに同様のpagination.phpを作成しても結果は同じでした。

Comment: すいません。。。勘違いしていたところがございました。。
確かに変更されないようで、カスタムしたメソッドを作成しないといけないようでした。
当方でも試してみて、上手くいけば情報共有させて頂きます。
誤情報をお伝えしてしまい、大変失礼致しました。